# Download ViewController from URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, server

In my app there should be at least 200 viewControllers or more. But not all the users uses all of the viewcontrollers. But this makes app so big, not all users may have enough storage. So I want to store this view controller files in my server. And after storing them I want to make them downloadable from url. For example user presses a button, then app downloads the viewcontroller file, and shows it to the user, then deletes the file. How could this be possible ? Or is it ? All I have is URL and don't know what to research. Any ideas could help me. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible as swift is a compiled and uninterpreted language

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start point : 
http://www.mirageapps.com/whats-new/articles/introspection-reflection-and-swizzling-in-objective-c (Reflection section)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the viewcontroller object are made on the fly and depending on how you implemented the app it will load only those viewcontrollers that the user go through.

Basically the viewcontrollers are added and removed from a stack and you can manage that using controllers like UINavigationController, UITabController etc.

Answer (score 0):

An idea to reduce the size could be to create forms dynamically with information that the server brings. for example a driver to edit the user (name, sex. etc...), you would only have a dynamic or generic driver that would be in charge of rendering and validating the content of a JSON that returns the server. exemple

```
 // JSON User Form
{ fields: [
    {
        name: "Full Name",
        type: "text",
        requiered: true
        ....
    }, {
       name: "Sex",
       type: "select",
       required: true
       options: ["Male", "Female"]
      ....
    }
]}
```

you can use libraries to create dynamic forms https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka